# How to remove unicode character in tinymce formatter.toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode, tinymce

What I am trying to do is to creating a markup element in my editor as like formatting tags ie, bold, italic.

For that I have defined custom formats while **tinymce.init** as

```
formats: {
    email: {inline: 'span', classes:'email', remove: 'all'}
}
```

and in my custom plugin have called `editor.formatter.toggle(markup);` for toggling selected text with `<span class="email" />`. Its working fine, but the problem is while toggling `<span class="email">abc@def.com</span>` what I am getting is the text is enclosed within the unicode character as `"&#65279;abc@def.com&#65279;"` this cause issue on further toggling. 
How to avoid the unicode character as like toggling working for formatting elements in tinymce?

Comment: you should decode those entities

Comment: the selection.getNode(); gives entire content while selecting the <span/> enclosed by unicode. So how to decode that @RajeshPatel

Comment: i have done this before , if you can provide me some js code like where you getting span values then i can sure i will help you

Comment: please join the chat room @RajeshPatel http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126786/tinymce-unicode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to my problem.

To prevent the enclosing of unicode character, added parameter `selector: "span"` to custom format

```
formats: {
    email: {inline: 'span', selector: 'span' classes:'email', remove: 'all', }
}
```

http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:formats

Answer (score 0):

```
    <span class="email">abc@def.com</span>
        <script>
              var emailval = $(".email").text();
              //If above is returning which you have mentioned :- "&#65279;abc@def.com&#65279;"  
Then what you can do it is you can decode that 



    var decemailval = $('<div/>').html(emailval).text();

    //Now decemailval should have proper text
    alert(decemailval);
        </script>
```

Comment: This is not possible have to toggle **span** with the selected text, which is using editor.selection.getNode()